# Setting value to input field using Vuex store modules

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex-modules

I have a vuex in module mode that fetching the data of a user:

**store/modules/users.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

export const state = () => ({
  user: {}
});

// Sets the values of data in states
export const mutations = {
  SET_USER(state, user) {
    state.user = user;
  }
};

export const actions = {
  fetchUser({ commit }, id) {
    console.log(`Fetching User with ID: ${id}`);
    return axios.get(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/users/${id}`)
      .then(response => {
        commit("SET_USER", response.data.data.result);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
};

// retrieves the data from the state
export const getters = {
  getUser(state) {
    return state.user;
  }
};
```

then on my template **pages/users/_id/index.vue**

```
<b-form-input v-model="name" type="text"></b-form-input>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      name: ""
    }
  },
  created() {
    // fetch user from API
    this.$store.dispatch("fetchUser", this.$route.params.id);
  }
}
```

Now I check the getters I have object **getUser** and I can see the attribute. How can I assign the **name** value from vuex getters to the input field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) is probably what you need

```
export default {
  // ...
  watch: {
    '$store.getters.getUser'(user) {
      this.name = user.name;
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: Nice I made it work. Thanks Jacob, in what lifecycle should I call the dispatch? Right now I'm calling it from beforeCreate()

Comment: There's no hard rules for this. Normally I do it in `created`. https://forum.vuejs.org/t/what-is-the-best-hook-to-call-api-to-load-initialisation-data-for-a-component/15167

Comment: I think that this use case calls for a computed property instead of a watcher

Comment: @AllenChun i think this is what Frank means. Not sure if it is what you want though. https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#two-way-computed-property

Comment: @JacobGoh Please check my answer. Regardless of whether you want a two-way binding you should use a computed property over watcher.

Answer (score 0):

While Jacob's answer isn't necessarily incorrect, it's better practice to use a computed property instead. You can read about that [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property)

```
  computed: {
    user(){
        return this.$store.getters.getUser
    }
  }
```

Then access name via `{{user.name}}` or create a name computed property

```
  computed: {
    name(){
        return this.$store.getters.getUser.name
    }
  }
```

Edit: fiddle as example https://jsfiddle.net/uy47cdnw/

Edit2: Please not that if you want to mutate object via that input field, you should use the link Jacob provided.

Comment: in some cases, you would be very right. I just don't think this is the case here. `v-model="name"` combine with a computed property without setter is going to be problematic. (god... i feel offended by the unreasonable downvote )

Comment: Initially my approach is using computed property but I need to mutate the object using input field, then I have 10 fields in my form so I find computed property really tedious. There's also an instance I used computed property to set the state and when I refreshed the page the value suddenly gone.